# rsnapshot backup fails with cryptomator mounted volume

Tags: macos, mount, rsync

I have rsnapshot (on macos) setup for my backups and in the config file one of the locations I am trying to back up is a Volume mounted by [Cryptomator](https://cryptomator.org/). Relevant line in config file:

```
backup  /Users/USERNAME/Documents/Cryptomator/SomeFolder/       localhost/
```

Within the Cryptomator software I have chosen a custom mount point.
The relevant output of the `mount` command is the following:

```
Cryptomator@macfuse0 on /Users/USERNAME/Documents/Cryptomator/SomeFolder (macfuse, nodev, nosuid, synchronous, mounted by USERNAME)
```

I am getting the following error once rsnapshot reaches the step where it is supposed to backup above mentioned folder:

```
rsync: opendir "/Users/USERNAME/Documents/Cryptomator/SomeFolder" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/0032d1ee-80fd-11ee-8227-6aecfccc70fe/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
WARNING: Some files and/or directories in /Users/USERNAME/Documents/Cryptomator/SomeFolder/ only transferred partially during rsync operation
/usr/bin/rsync -a --delete --numeric-ids --relative --delete-excluded \
    /Users/USERNAME/Documents/Cryptomator/SomeFolder/ \
    /Volumes/HARDDRIVENAME/Snapshots/alpha.0/localhost/
```

My guess is that the config file should not reference localhost for that mounted volume but something else. How do I reference the mounted Volume correctly so rsnapshot can do a backup of it?